# Build an array from two others and display the values with some special conditions

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

Here is my Array A => [index] value:

```
[0] 0
[1] 0
[2] 0
[3] 1
[4] 0
[5] 100
[6] 0
```

and here is my Array B => [index] value:

```
[0] 0
[1] 1
[2] 12
[3] 430
[4] 0
[5] 0
[6] 0
```

The purpose is to combine the first array and the second array in a third one in order to display :

- pairs in which **not both values are 0**
- to **keep the index** value

Thus my Array C would behave this way => [index] value:

```
[1] 0 1
[2] 0 12
[3] 1 430
[5] 100 0
```

How to combine and to print this result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Please reread about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We will help you fix problems in an honest attempt to solve the problem; we won't simply do what looks remarkably like a homework assignment for you.

Comment: There aren't many interesting ways to work with arrays in shell (they're not meant to build meaningful data structures; they're a way to preserve lists of arguments containing whitespace). Whatever dead simple, brute-force approach you can find to do this is *probably* "the" way to do it.

Comment: The expected output in your example doesn't fit your description of the desired behavior. You said *"only values that are **both not** equal to 0"* and included pairs like `0 1` and `100 0` in which some values are zero. Did you mean *"pairs in which **not both** values are 0"*?

Comment: @Socowi: This is correct, it seems that my english is not as good as yours!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think that my example is as clear as spring water but I took your point! And I am an honest person and I am not a student :)

Comment: @chepner: Thank you again for your comment.

Comment: Your description of the problem to be solved is clear enough. What is totally lacking is what you’d tried to solve the problem.

Comment: OK @JonathanLeffler I did not understand. No problem, next time I will show my reflexion. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the arrays are equal length.

```
a=(0 0 0 1 0 100 0); b=(0 1 12 430 0 0 0)
c=(); for k in "${!a[@]}"; 
do if [[ "${a[k]}" -ne 0 ]] || [[ "${b[k]}" -ne 0 ]]; 
  then c[k]="${a[k]} ${b[k]}"; fi; 
done


for k in "${!c[@]}"; do echo "$k: ${c[$k]}"; done
```

will print

```
1: 0 1
2: 0 12
3: 1 430
5: 100 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @karakfa your answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If we may assume they are the same length -

```
for (( ndx=0; ndx < "${#a[@]}"; ndx++ ))
do if (( a[ndx] || b[ndx] ))
   then c[ndx]="${a[ndx]} ${b[ndx]}"
        echo "$ndx: ${c[ndx]}"
   fi
done
```

If you don't know if they are the same, or which is longer -

```
for (( ndx=0;
       ndx < ( ${#a[@]} > ${#b[@]} ? ${#a[@]} : ${#b[@]}) ; 
       ndx++ ));
do if (( a[ndx] || b[ndx] ))
   then c[ndx]="${a[ndx]} ${b[ndx]}"
        echo "$ndx: ${c[ndx]}"
   fi
done
```

This compares array lengths with the ternary operator and picks whichever is longer.

Comment: The test `a + b` is not "values that are both not equal to 0" -- what if a == 1 and b == -1 ?

Comment: True. Should have asked if negatives were possible. - or fractions, for that matter.

Comment: Thanks @PaulHodges for your reply! This solution works too.